# "Where did […]?" versus "Where have […]?"

Tags: present-perfect, american-english, past-simple

My friend planned to visit my country for a week. Now it is his 3rd day he has been in my country. I want to know which places (did he visit)/(has he visited), so that I can recommend him other places to visit. Which question would be correct? I don't know which tense would be correct to use.

*Question: (Are 4 ways below correct to use?)

(1) Where did you visit?

(2) Where did you visit in the last few days?

(3) Where have you visited?

(4) Where have you visited since you came here?

*Answer: ( Are both ways below correct to use?)

(1) I visited X, Y, Z.

(2) I have visited X, Y,Z.

My friends tell me that we can even use the simple past here in the US. I would like to hear more about the US speaks’ opinions about this matter.
And if the simple past is also correct to use, could you please explain the difference between them (the simple past and the present perfect)?

Comment: The perfect tense is always correct when the visit to the country is ongoing - "What places have you visited so far?". As a BrE speaker, I'm not sure whether Americans would find the simple past acceptable as well.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for your answer. I also would like to hear opinions from AmE speakers.

Comment: I'm Canadian, and we agree with the Brits on this. It's my experience with Americans that they frequently use simple past where I would only use present perfect, but I can't say for sure if this is one of those contexts.

Comment: thank you gotube and Kate. We have to wait for a US speaker's confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

AmE. In terms of the questions, the perfect tense sounds correct:

- What have you seen so far?
- Where have you visited so far?

This implies an ongoing trip.  "Did" would make more sense if the vacation had completed, and the visitor had returned home. Then you ask "What did you do there?"

Answers, during the ongoing visit:

- Well, we went to the museum (in the morning).
- We saw the Eiffel Tower (yesterday).

That's 'simple past'. It looks like the commenter who wrote "Americans frequently use simple past" may have some knowledge about the answer.

Comment: Hi Same, thank you for your answer. In this link, I posted a similar situation, but the answers from the natives recommended that I can use either. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335421/ame-repeated-actions-until-the-present-simple-past-or-present-perfect

Comment: "I (visited)/ (have visited) Thailand 2 times. It is a nice country. I think you should visit it once in your life." The action of visiting may still happen in the future if the speaker still has chance to go, then I can use either tense. But why in my example I can't use the simple past "where did you go?".

Comment: That is the reason I am confused, for repeated actions until now, when I can use either tense, when I can't.

Comment: You are asking: why can't you use the simple past such as ""where did you go?"  If you phrase it "where did you go yesterday", or "what did you do this morning", then it's acceptable.  That is, a specific time frame, which is now done and completed, then it can be simple past.

Comment: In the visiting Thailand example, there is also no specific time, but why I can still use the simple past?

Comment: In general, both are valid grammatical tenses, so you have to consider the meaning. One is about something in the past that has finished, and the other is about something in the past that continues up until this moment (and perhaps beyond), and affects the present.  Occasionally, both tenses are fine options.

Comment: This means that I still can use the simple past without specific time (like yesterday, last week...) for this context. Am I right?

Comment: Presumably there are dozens of articles on the internet about these English verb tenses. You should read multiple sources of information.  Whichever grammatical tense you pick, it will make sense to the listener, even if it's somewhat wrong.  The problem with "did" (simple past) is you are implying they are done, finished.   In the specific case of an ongoing current vacation, are they done? No.  So, it's not the ideal choice.  But it still makes sense. It just sounds slightly "off" (by that, I mean "wrong").

Comment: I have another situation, in an interview, I would tell to the interviewer about my work experience : “I (worked/ have worked) for different companies specializing in oil production. “ As an American speaker, Is it still correct and sound good to use the simple past here? Or the present perfect sounds better?

Comment: Does the simple past sound off /wrong in this sentence: "I VISITED Thailand 2 times. It is a nice country. I think you should visit it once in your life."?

Comment: Of course every sentence is different. "I've visited Thailand twice" seems very good, but there are cases where "I visited Thailand two times" would also work. It depends on the situational context.

Comment: I already provided the context that I want to give my friend advice on where he should visit . If so, in this context, is the simple past good to use here?

Comment: I will stop commenting now since you have asked for a bounty, which means you are requesting other people's input, which is fine.